# How to query records having at least one valid child record?

Tags: soql

I am attempting to create a query with the objects `Opportunity`, `Courses__c`, and `Prior_Qualifications__c`.

`Opportunity` has parent-child relationships with both `Courses__c` and `Prior_Qualifications__c`. I want to be able to query only information with valid `Courses__c` records, so that I can disregard any results returned with valid `Opportunity` object information, but no `Courses__c` information. Is there a way to do this? Am I able to make a query such that:

```
Select Id, 
(Select Course_Name__c
from Courses__r)
from Opportunity
where Courses__r.Course_Name__c != ''
```

I know that this isn't a valid query... but can I do something like this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What about something like:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    (SELECT
        Id
    FROM
        Courses__r)
FROM
    Opportunity
WHERE
    Id IN (SELECT Opportunity__c from Courses__c WHERE Course_Name__c != '')
```

This will get you all of the opportunities with a valid course.

Comment: Nice. Can he just query the Courses object with non-blank names and then do group by Opportunity__c field? Just one query instead of two?

Comment: I didn't know you could do an `in` selector in the `where` portion of the queries. This makes my life a whole lot simpler... Thanks!

Comment: Just take care that your Courses__c table isn't too big.  If you query in the where clause has a lot of rows it could hit governor limits are just run slow.

Answer (score 1):

Move your `WHERE` clause into your subquery:

```
SELECT Id, 
    (SELECT Course_Name__c
        FROM Courses__r
        WHERE Course_Name__c != '')
FROM Opportunity
```

Comment: That does work, but it returns `Opportunity` objects without any `Courses__r` data.

Comment: Yea, you could also do it this way. You would then have to filter through your opportunities however and remove any with a `Courses__r.size() == 0`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to return opportunities with no course, you can query on that object and group to get the ordering correct.

```
SELECT Opportunity__c, Course_Name__c
FROM Courses__c
WHERE Opportunity__c != null AND Course_Name__c != null
ORDER BY Opportunity__c
```